# Is there a faster way to check a pandas column for a string than this? My loop is taking a long time to complete

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes.

I am going row by row and trying to check if a value in df1[column] is in df2[column], and record this info to df1.

I have a 'toy' example below. But my actual dataset has 150,000 rows.

The below code runs fine, but on the larger dataset I actually had to stop the kernel it was taking too long.

```
df1= pd.DataFrame([['1', 'a'],
                   ['2', 'b'],
                   ['3', 'b'],
                   ['4', 'z'],
                   ['5', 'e']], columns=['num', 'num_letter'])


# adding an extra column to record result of check for duplicates



df1['dupe'] = None


df2= pd.DataFrame([['1', 'a'],
                   ['2', 'b'],
                   ['3', 'b'],
                   ['4', 'd'],
                   ['5', 'e']], columns=['num', 'num_letter'])


for i in range(len(df1)):

    for k in df1['num_letter']:

# if value from df1 is found in df2 column,
# record the word 'dupe' to corresponding empty cell in df1. 

        if k in df2['num_letter'].values:

            df1.loc[i,'dupe'] = 'dupe'

        else:

            df1.loc[i,'dupe'] = 'not_dupe'
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks folks

Comment: First of all, you're looping twice.  You don't need to `for i in range(len(df1)):` **and** `for k in df1['num_letter']:`

Comment: You're right. That's really silly of me. What can I use to index this section if I don't have an `i` to loop?

`df1.loc[i,'dupe'] = 'dupe'`

Comment: `df1['dupe'] = np.where(df1.num_letter.isin(df2.num_letter), 'dupe', 'not_dupe')` ?

Comment: you want `df1.num_letter.isin(df2.num_letter)`.

Comment: @ChrisA this is much faster. Thanks. Can't mark it as an answer tho!

Comment: @SCool awesome. You can mark piRSquared's answer, it's very much in the same vein

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Numpy's `in1d` and `where`

```
df1.assign(dupe=np.where(np.in1d(df1.num_letter, df2.num_letter), 'dupe', 'not_dupe'))

  num num_letter      dupe
0   1          a      dupe
1   2          b      dupe
2   3          b      dupe
3   4          z  not_dupe
4   5          e      dupe
```